# How do I make devices initialize faster when plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Is there any way of speeding driver lookup on Windows 7 for certain frequently plugged-in devices?

I've got a mobile internet key that I use (maybe not often enough) and it takes forever to lookup and load the seven or eight drivers it needs to operate. (it's also a disk drive and something else)

I'd really like that particular device to load faster. (letting it always plugged is a non-viable option)

Using more than a mouse, I noticed **windows seems to remember** (and cache) which mouse driver it used the previous time, but as soon as I switch to the second mouse and then back, it does a long driver scan again.

I wonder if there's a way of specifying a list of drivers with **priority over the others** or something like that.

Comment: (I don't like the new title Tom gave to the question, but if it helps getting answers, I'll stay with it)

Comment: only thing i can think of, Clean up your enumerations, and devices, and always plug the item into the exact same port location. When you plop it into a new location, the system starts all over again.

We discovered this long ago, and it has not changed, so we began to Label items that are in the many USB ports, so when cleaning up the computer or whatever, the wire goes back in the same place it came out of.
Same thing with Mass storage or anything else, I always TRY and have a place for it , and put it back in its place.  Little stickey numbers are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this forum. It sounds like these people have had the same issue that you are. It was Microsoft techs responding back so I wouldn't hold too dear to what they're saying, but there were some interesting suggestions that may work well for you since this is a different kind of device than what they were discussing.

[answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/usb-devices-slow-to-be-recognized-programs-using/e017d7d2-373d-4941-b25d-f4e5fa47ae23)

[technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/dcf814a4-976c-48db-9bb2-e12979d787a8)

Comment: this one sounded plausable. .
marwinious "Chipset drivers for my motherboard as well as the USB drivers"